# How to match the data dynamically from a file

Tags: perl

I am having  a output in a file. 3 blocks of output i am having. Data in the file is

```
*******Block A********
iSCSI_Storage=0
User=Admin
IP=15.178.209.111

*****end of block A******

*******Block B********
iSCSI_Storage=1
User=Admin_1
IP=15.178.209.111

*****end of block B******

*******Block C********
iSCSI_Storage=2
User=Admin_2
IP=15.178.209.111

*****end of block C******
```

I want to delete the first block of the code and i have to check whether other blocks are present in the file or not. Also i have to make sure that the data of block A should not be present in the file. Our file will have only 2 blocks now.

Similarly after the first operation, i have to delete the last block and check for the same conditions and at last i have to delete the remaining block.

Please tell me the efficient way to do this.

Comment: i have accepted but still it is showing 0. I am new tostack overflow.

Comment: @Nitesh - No, I've glanced over all of your questions, and you have yet to accept an answer by clicking on the check-mark-shaped area underneath the vote total for a given answer.

Comment: @Karthik: How to do that. Is that somthing like voting or some other thing. Do i have to upvote?

Comment: @Nitesh:) Liar we all saw your profile and you say "i have accepted but still it is showing 0." which is indeed not possible at all. Where did you accept?

Comment: @Lion: Sorry i am new to stack overflow. I thought voting up is like accepting. Now see

Comment: Thanks to all. Stackoverflow is a very helpful forum. Thanks for all your support

Comment: @Nitesh: You can done this with the help of log4cxx.Refer this link http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/

Comment: @Jack: It is a output i am getting from running a command. By using some other commands say "delete block A", Block A will get deleted. I have to check whether this change is correctly reflected or not. Do u need more clarification jack?

Comment: @Nitesh - Okay, what have you tried?

Comment: @Nitesh:) Don't mind at all. Anyway, I have voted your question up.

Comment: @Jack: Wait for 5 minutes. I am giving you my code in a simpler terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to first verify that you can remove the first block, then remove it. Assuming a subroutine can be used for this purpose, you might get away with using something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @blocks;
my $block = "";
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^\Q*******\E/ .. /^\Q*****end of\E/) {
        $block .= $_;
        if (/^\Q*****end of\E/) {
            push @blocks, $block;
            $block = "";
        }
    }
}
my $data = shift @blocks;
print $data if verify_block($data);
print @blocks;

sub verify_block {
    ... # enter code here
}
__DATA__
*******Block A********
iSCSI_Storage=0
User=Admin
IP=15.178.209.111

*****end of block A******

*******Block B********
iSCSI_Storage=1
User=Admin_1
IP=15.178.209.111

*****end of block B******

*******Block C********
iSCSI_Storage=2
User=Admin_2
IP=15.178.209.111

*****end of block C******
```